# Why does MS Expression Recorder make the capture area blank/white in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, screen-capture, screen-recorder, microsoft-expression

I have had this problem on 2 different virtual machines running Windows XP SP3. Basically, you can still see the green cross-hairs and outline while Expression Recorder is recording, but everything else inside the capture area is blank/white.

[image: screencap describing the problem]

Why is this happening, and what can I do to resolve it?

EDIT: It seems to work fine when I use Windows Virtual PC with XP Mode, so I guess we can say the problem is with VMware Workstation.  How do I get it working on VMware Workstation 8.0.1?

Comment: Post a link to a screenshot here in the comments and someone will edit it in.

Comment: Can you try on a physical installation of XP? If one's not available, try another VM product. Perhaps the virtual graphics hardware in the VMs you're using is causing this.